# Is it possible to enable Aero Glass again in Windows 10 for Windows titles?

Tags: aero, transparency, windows-10

I've updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and I miss the Aero Glass transparency that I had in Windows 7.

How can I enable this again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows 10 doesn't include this by default. [Microsoft removed it in Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/05/18/creating-the-windows-8-user-experience.aspx).

But there is a 3rd party developer who created a small DLL to restore the glass in Windows 8 and now Windows 10.

To re- enable Aero Glass, [go to his website and download the installer (starting with Version 1.4 it supports Windows 10 (July 2015 Version Build 10240) and in Version 1.4.5 it supports Windows 10 Version 1511 Build 10586)](http://glass8.eu/download).

If you use Windows 10 anniversary update Version 1607, you have to download and install the version up to 1.5.3.

If you use Windows 10 Creators update Version 1703, you have to download and install the version starting with Version 1.5.4 (as of 2017-09-09, last version is 1.5.5, but only for x64 systems, if you have x86 only hardware and want Aero Glass stay at anniversary update Version 1607 and use version 1.5.3)

If you use Windows 10 Fall Creators update Version 1709 (Build 16299, you have to download and install the version starting with Version 1.5.7.

If you use Windows 10 October 2018 update Version 1809 (Build 17763, you have to download and install the version starting with Version 1.5.10.

Run the Installer and install it to `C:\AeroGlass`.

Now you have Aero Glass back:

[image]

[image]

Starting with version 1.5.2 for Windows 10 anniversary update Version 1607, you can use `regsvr32.exe DWMGlass.dll` to enable Aero Glass for Windows Store apps:

[image]

To get rid of the watermark, donate 2-3€/$ via Paypal to [get access to his website](http://www.glass8.eu/sign/) and download a `donation.key` file which has to be placed under `C:\AeroGlass`.

Comment: @Warning this is a TESTING preview so the debug Windows is there to show more detail. In the final Aero Glass DLL this window will be removed.

Comment: How come taskbar icons from the screenshot are not scaled, did you change something in order to achieve this effect?

Comment: @Klaster_1 I also sue StartIsBack++ (http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557) and here I can make the icons larger. The default size is too small for me.

Comment: Wow, now that is Magic, Andre....

Comment: I got a question about the [background pattern](http://orig06.deviantart.net/7264/f/2010/305/0/4/black_aero_glass_background_by_raith2006-d31zizr.png) of the design on Windows 10. If you move the window, will it follow statically, or will it stick a bit to the desktop, thus move slower like in Windows 7? I really liked it the way it was in Windows 7. But this did not work on Windows 8 when I tried this.

Comment: try this Win7 theme: http://sagorpirbd.deviantart.com/art/Aero-7-Themes-for-Windows-10-523979941 and look if it works . Currently I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @modiX in an upcoming StartisBack++ update you get the Win7 taskbar back: http://superuser.com/a/1150671/174557 if this is what you want to know.