# Can I enable the Windows 7 Start menu in Windows 10?

Tags: start-menu, windows-10

I've upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and now I only find this new slower Start menu with all the tiles in it

[image: http://szamtechnikus.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Win10Startmenu.png]
*(picturesource: http://szamtechnikus.hu)*

Can I enable the older Windows 7 one again which suites my needs more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the inbox tools of Windows it is not possible. But because Windows 8 missed the start menu at all (it only included a Startscreen), a lot of 3rd party developers created start menus.

2 Important tools are **StartIsBack++** and **ClassicShell**.

[StartIsBack++](http://startisback.com/) is the Windows 10 compatible version of StartIsBack+ which works in Windows 8.1 and comes as a [30 day free trial which you have to unlock for a few bucks](http://startisback.com/#buy-tab). It restore the Windows 7 Start menu best and provides a lot of configuration options. It [can be downloaded on http://startisback.com/](http://startisback.com/#download-tab).

[image]

ClassicShell 4.2.4 is also supporting Windows 10 and can also bring back the classic Windows XP/2000 start menu if needed. It is free to use.

The [latest version can be found on their website](http://www.classicshell.net/downloads/).

After setup, run the config program and select the older XP style

[image]

or the newer Windows 7 style:

[image]

Now you have your loved start menu back and not the slower XAML based start from Windows 10.

Comment: What is your source for the start menu being XAML?

Comment: @Gusdor the Startscreen is hosted by the **shellexperiencehost.exe** and when you look at the stack, you see XAML calls. Here are suers who had crashes of Start (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop/start-menu-not-working-in-windows-10/a09dd25f-c180-4d4b-b02c-1ec7e1a328f5?auth=1) and here you use the XAML DLL **Windows.UI.Xaml.dll**

Comment: @Gusdor - Microsoft literally said it was.  Before it was the start menu in Windows 10 was looked significantly different.  There is even an effort to determine if it possible to use the code that does exist to bring it back through third-party software.  The first few builds of the Windows 10 Technical preview had what is believed to be the start menu that would have made it to Windows 8.2 before it was canceled.