# How do I see Recent Documents per Application in the Windows 10 Start Menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, start-menu, documents

I just moved from Windows 7 to 10.  The Windows 7 start menu would show me recent documents.  I found this convenient.  It looked like this:

[image]

Now in Windows 10, I don't see a "Recent" list lie in Windows 7.  Instead I see this ugliness.  Is there a way to get some sort of recent list when I hover over an application icon?

[image]

Comment: install StartiSback++ or ClassicShell to get it back: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557. the Win10 start menu sucks http://superuser.com/a/1132380/174557

Comment: While it doesn't function in the same manner, I utilize a shortcut based upon the answer from **thilina R** in the question I referenced:  *"Method 2: Make a desktop shortcut to the folder 'Recent Items'"*  Ultimately, you can pin that to your All Programs list and your Start Menu.  When you open it, sort by the *Modified* column and it becomes very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 will only show the most used apps, and recently added apps. Sadly there is no such thing as recent used in the windows 10 start menu.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that Microsoft applications (i.e. Word, Outlook) have this feature built-in.  For example, if I were reading a PDF and later used Outlook to create an email that required an attachement, the first suggestion would most likely be that PDF as well as a few other recent documents.

Perhaps this could be Microsoft's new direction with regard to 'Recent Documents'...

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.