# Application specific frequently used items in Windows 10 Start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I am missing the Windows 7 Start menu feature in Windows 10 that shows application-specific last used items for every pinned application in the Start menu and where you can pin some frequently used items. For example [frequently used places visited using RDP](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/50628970-6a23-489f-a65b-9749a1e79fb6/how-to-save-remote-desktop-connections):

[image: Start Menu]

It is [NOT globally last used documents](https://superuser.com/questions/1128413/is-recent-documents-no-longer-provided-in-windows-10-start-menu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), it is application-specific last used documents, URL, places, addresses, etc.

It used to work this way:

> Please right-click Remote Desktop Connection icon in Accessories of
>   Start Menu, and then choose pin to Start Menu.
>   All the connections you recently used will be listed in it and you can
>   also pin them in the list.

Is there a way in Windows 10 to achieve that without installing any third-party software?

Comment: At this time, if you right-click an application within the Start Menu or All Apps list, [it will show you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dJrt.jpg) a list of `Recent` items that also has a `Pin to this list` option.

Comment: @Run5k oh, did not see the list because have not launched any session yet, either put this as an aswer or I shall delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although many things have changed within the user interface as it evolved between Windows 7 and Windows 10, this one essentially stayed the same.

If you right-click an application within the Windows 10 Start Menu or All Apps list, it will show you a list of `Recent` items that also has a `Pin to this list` option:

[image: Pin to this list]