# Showing recent documents on the Taskbar Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Due to this answer

[Is "Recent Documents" no longer provided in Windows 10 Start Menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1128413/is-recent-documents-no-longer-provided-in-windows-10-start-menu/1405003#1405003)

I tried to  create a new Toolbar... and put in the local address to the Recent folder to get access to the entire list, regardless of the program used.

But Windows shows me the message, that the Recent foldername is not valid. How can I make it run? Which setting did I miss?

Comment: More details would improve this question

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- Open Explorer and navigate to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows`
- Right-click the folder "Recent Items" and select "Pin to Start"
- The tile will appear in the Start menu. Click it to open the folder.

[source](https://winaero.com/pin-recent-files-to-the-start-menu-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score -1):

I know that. That is not my problem. I want the tile or the symbol in the taskbar, just like in the picture, statet in my first post [Is "Recent Documents" no longer provided in Windows 10 Start Menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1128413/is-recent-documents-no-longer-provided-in-windows-10-start-menu/1405003#1405003)

Comment: Commentary should never be submitted as an answer to a question.