# Is it possible to remove right side of start menu on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

Is it possible to completely remove the right side of the start menu? I have unpinned all of the apps from there but now it shows only empty area on the right side, it does not let me resize it. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: From a few articles I saw during the preview, it was possible. What does it look like when you unpin everything? A screenshot would help for the after result. Are there any groups/categories left that you can remove?

Comment: use StartIsBack++, which is a lot faster and brings back to much better WinVista/7 Start menu: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557

Answer (score 4):

Right click every icon & Unpin from Start

Importantly - it needs a reboot.

The right side doesn't collapse immediately, it's just empty... but it can then be dragged out of sight by hovering over the right-hand edge & dragging.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the icons and remove all of them.  The right side will collapse when they are all gone and you can drag the corner and set the size of the menu that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click to unpin those apps, which are on the right side of your start menu. But the right side will still exist, even though all the apps are gone.

Then you need to click on anywhere on the desktop to close the start menu and click start again. The right side of the start menu disappears.

[image]