# Windows 10 Start Menu Editing

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, start-menu

It seems that on Windows 10 I cannot add new items to the "All apps" part of the Start Menu. I tried moving a shortcut to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, but the program did not show up anywhere under the All apps view. Looking for the cause, I tried changing the name of one of the files already present in the aforementioned folder. To my surprise, the shortcut I renamed no longer shows up on the All apps view at all. Renaming it back to its original name did not bring it back. What could be causing this problem?

**Update:** Since I posted this question, I have noticed that the "Most used" applications are no longer updating.

**Update 2:** Since my last update, the issue seems to have somehow been resolved. I will look into possible causes for the resolution.

Comment: [You have to create a folder first](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/10529-all-apps-start-menu-add-remove-items-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: @Moab I don't think this is the case. There are already many items in the `Programs` folder that appear on the Start Menu. I also just tried putting the  shortcut I wanted to add into a new folder I created within the `Programs` folder, but this folder does not appear either.

Comment: Use a better Startmenu: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557

Comment: @Moab I suppose I could downgrade to Windows 8.1, but that doesn't exactly solve my problem because of 8/8.1's lack of start menus. As far as using a non-Windows OS, it is not really feasible for me to make a movement away from Windows at this time, especially given the relative significance of this issue.

Comment: That is why I have stuck with W7. When it is no longer a valid OS I will move to some flavor of Linux.

Comment: install StartIsBack++ and you have the Win7 Startmenu

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. i searched read and tried everything. What  I did find out on my own, I use CCleaner, When You open Ccleaner to main window, On the right side scroll down to windows explorer, and Check All,except wipe free space.

Then click run.  uncheck all and restart computer.

Comment: Trying this did not seem to have any effect. What version of CCleaner are you using? On the newest version, the options are on the left side, and "Wipe Free Space" is under the advanced category. What boxes are under yours?