# Why doesn't Windows 10 start menu find items from ProgramData?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I am looking in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\` and all my apps are there. However, when I open `All Apps` or type something into `Search Windows` box, not all the apps are there - some are simply not found. Why is this?

Comment: use StartIsBack++ and not this Win10 crap thing: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557

Comment: YOU NEED much more explaining to do. Details, details, man!

Comment: 1. Does this happen is safe mode? 2. How many apps do you have? 3. ARE they all really pinned to C:\...\Programs\? 4. Do you have an anti-virus installed? 5. What programs (NAMES) does this happen to? 6. What programs (FILE EXTENSTIONS) does this happen to? 7. When did this start to happen? 8. Are all the programs pinned to `C:\Users\RandomUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` work?  9. What processes  are running in the background when this first happens (please view these without any open applications.)? 10. Does this happen to all users? 11. If not, which types of

Comment: users does this happen to?

Answer (score 4):

Windows search results only include things that are in indexed locations.  You can open "Indexing Options" to see which locations are included.  By default, the "Program Files" folder is not included.

The programs that appear under "All Apps" are the ones that have shortcuts in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\".  Some programs may choose to install themselves without adding anything to that menu.  But you can always create a shortcut and place it in the folder yourself.

Comment: Your claim that programs in All Apps appear under that path is only _partially_ correct. Some apps appear there, some do not.