# Start Menu in Windows 10 suddenly closes when right clicking on username

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

When you right click on your username in Windows 10, at least for me, **the whole Start Menu suddenly closes** (by either waiting around or moving your mouse around. you also can't click on anything) Why this is happening is beyond me.

I know I could sign out using <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>**X**</kbd> or switch using using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> but I think it's really handy being able to easily switch to another other user (in my case, a user called "Development"). Basically. **I want to fix this and I want it to work**.

I've found absolutely nothing remotely related to my problem online, and it's happening on newly created users as well.

[image]

`ShellExperienceHost.exe` crashes every time. The event log is below:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          10/23/2015 12:30:48 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Jordan-Desktop
Description:
Faulting application name: ShellExperienceHost.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16515, time stamp: 0x55fa599a
Faulting module name: StartUI.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16515, time stamp: 0x55fa5463
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x00000000001c01cb
Faulting process id: 0xd6c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d10d4b5b06e206
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartUI.dll
Report Id: 8e43e43b-a845-4d31-840e-5f5ff6c39a82
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10240.16384_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-10-23T04:30:48.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>9249</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Jordan-Desktop</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>ShellExperienceHost.exe</Data>
    <Data>10.0.10240.16515</Data>
    <Data>55fa599a</Data>
    <Data>StartUI.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.10240.16515</Data>
    <Data>55fa5463</Data>
    <Data>80000003</Data>
    <Data>00000000001c01cb</Data>
    <Data>d6c</Data>
    <Data>01d10d4b5b06e206</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartUI.dll</Data>
    <Data>8e43e43b-a845-4d31-840e-5f5ff6c39a82</Data>
    <Data>Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10240.16384_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy</Data>
    <Data>App</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Running the **System Maintenance troubleshooter** didn't work. The results are below:

[image]

I generated a crash dump of `ShellExperienceHost.exe`. [ [Download here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67289085/ShellExperienceHost.exe.24188.dmp) ]

Comment: I saw this problem on a machine that had an old version of WordPoint translation software. Do you have any software on your machine that tries to intercept mouse hover position over other windows?

Comment: I combed through and [didn't see anything](https://pastebin.com/AVtPUaHU) that stuck out. I'm glad you said that though because it seems like a step in the right direction.

Comment: Can you reproduce the perform if the computer is running in Safe Mode? That could narrow it down to whether it is a driver problem, a hardware problem, or a program that is running.

Comment: look in event log if the shellexperiencehost.exe crashed. if es, post the error message

Comment: @magicandre1981 It did and it crashes every time I do it. ([Full log](https://pastebin.com/arekcBNh))

Comment: @MosheKatz It happens in Safe Mode. And ShellExperienceHost.exe crashed again. Here's the [full event log](https://pastebin.com/anFau5iz) for when it happened in safe mode. (Not sure if the event log makes a difference in safe mode or out)

Comment: I assume build 10240 but somebody was running a 2 month old expired build yesterday and asked how to move past it.  So what build of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound All of the file versions listed in the linked event log say 10240.

Comment: I cannot access pastebin at my current location.  I would appreciate in the future for questions like that just to be answered and more importantly added into the question itself.

Comment: Have you tried running *System Maintenance troubleshooter*? A Microsoft Answers post suggests doing that for this problem. 1) Press **Win** + **X** keys, then click *Control Panel*. 2) Click *Troubleshooting*. (If you don't see this option, click *View By* and choose *Small Icons*). 3) Click *View all*. 4) Click *System Maintenance*. 5) Click *Next* and follow the instructions.

Comment: ok, I need a crash dump to see more details. Follow the steps from here: http://pastebin.com/tU3Agf5M and share the generated dmp (compressed) files.

Comment: Will report back probably tomorrow. Thanks all

Comment: were you able to capture a crash dump?

Comment: @MosheKatz check edited post with results of the troubleshooter

Comment: @magicandre1981 check edited post for the dump

Comment: @Ramhound and yes, 10240 is my build. is this not current?

Comment: I can't see any useful thing from the dump. The error code means Breakpoint, so some debug code is triggered. Others also have this crash: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/my-start-menu-is-closing-after-click-on-the-user/a5e0b7fc-9866-4768-a70c-912f343da742 In November, Microsoft releases a new Win10 Build (TH2) with fixes and new features. Wait for this update and test it again. I hate the new start menu and in my VM I use **StartIsBack++**: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557

Comment: adding a **bounty** won't help. We can't fix a bug in the Microsoft code.

Comment: @magicandre1981 meh

Comment: make a system image, join the Insider Program and try the latest Insider Build. Maybe this fixes the issue