# What is the simplest way to see long program names in the Windows 10 Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, filenames

I'm having an issue in Windows 10 where I have two different programs with similar titles. I only ever really want to open one of them (one's an IDE, the other is the accompanying documentation).

[image]

If you can't see the image above, both programs have titles starting with the text "Code Composer Studio 6.1.0" and have the same icon. To tell the difference, you have to see the end of the file name. However the titles are too long and get truncated in the Windows 10 Start Menu.

Is there any way to widen this part of the Start Menu? It's a pain to have to "open containing folder" or whatever every time.

Comment: Does right  click "properties" allow you to change the name?

Comment: use StartIsBack++: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557

Comment: @DavidPostill : yeah, actually I hadn't thought about changing the name of the file itself.  That might be the best answer.