# Start menu broken and Icons completely missing

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

So that's the best I could do with the title. 
It all started when I was playing skyrim and it crashed, I couldn't open task manager so I signed out and signed in again. After that I couldn't click on anything in my taskbar that had to do with windows (sound manager, notifications) and I couldn't open the start menu or search anything in the search box. I could open programs from the taskbar.

So I search online for a fix to this issue and I found [This page](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/start-menu-does-not-open-windows-10)
Nothing helped until step 4.
After completing step 4 the task menu actually opened and I could click on everything else normally
BUT all of the programs from the start menu were gone, even the documents option above settings is gone. 
[Only windows apps are not missing and are functional.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwkhD.png)
I can't add anything in the start menu either.
 When I tried to at least activate the documents shortcut from personilization I found out that everything except settings was grayed out.

Restarted the computer, restarted explorer.exe.No results. 
Nothing, and I mean NOTHING has annoyed me as much as this has.

Comment: I also found out that my pc has slowed down in general. Games are running worse and boot up slower. This issue is awful.

Comment: Sounds like a HDD that is failing.  Everything you describe can be explained by a HDD that has bad sectors, run SFC and DISM to confirm, post results in question itself ( not a comment )

Comment: the new Startmenu sucks and often has such issues. Try StartIsBack++: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it could be a bad HDD, something like that is usually caused by a corrupted OS. 
Try refreshing the install before buying a new HDD. 
(Refresh reinstalls system data without deleting personal data)

Here are instructions:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/refresh-is-part-of-reset-in-windows-10

(I know the explanation of refresh was not 100% accurate, but it serves as a general explanation)

Comment: Right...A OS does not just become corrupt without a reason.

Comment: Agreed, but that reason can be anything from power surge to ...well, anything. 
The OP mentioned Skyrim crashing as the catalyst. (Which certainly could have been caused by a bad HDD... or any number of other things)
I would certainly not rule out HDD as an issue, but refreshing the install is both less expensive and easier all around than replacing the drive, so IMHO, I would try that first.

Comment: @Michael If the drive **is about to fail the first thing to do is a backup** while you can still read the drive. That should be done before any attempt at a refresh.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted sir but that fixed the issue. That + restarting windows explorer for some reason. It also fixed the issue with everything being slower in general. My windows files are on an SSD and it's relatively new. So I doubt that's the reason it happened but all I can do now is wait and see. 
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

[Refreshing windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/refresh-is-part-of-reset-in-windows-10) fixed my issue. I honestly don't know what caused it. I don't think my drives had anything to do with it but I can't say with certainty. Anyway thank you.