# Get Excel jump list to appear on Windows 10

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-office, jumplist

I recently upgraded to Windows 10. I discovered that my Excel jump list has disappeared. I can see the jump list of other softwares such as Firefox. How do I make the Excel jump list appear?

I am using Office 2013.

Comment: where is the jump lost missing? Taskbar or Startmenu?

Comment: Missing from Startmenu

Comment: try a different startmenu tool: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557 and look if it shows the jumplists

Comment: Have you checked the `Advanced Options / Display` for number of `Recent Documents`?