# Cannot read Windows 10 program list

Tags: windows, windows-10

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 last year.  I have never been able to read the names of the programs installed because it only shows the first x characters as shown below:

[image]

If you have programs with multiple versions then I sometimes have to "guess", which one is the correct one to open.  Is there a way of displaying the entire program names.

Comment: A screenshot would help ...

Comment: use a better startmenu like StartIsBack++: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557