# should I remove sihost.exe? it seems to crash my whole explorer (taskbar) regularly

Tags: windows-10, crash, taskbar, services

I am using windows 10; a few days ago I started noticing my whole taskbar with my desktop icons plus desktop wallpaper to disappear (everything goes black) for about 5 seconds. then everything starting up again.

i was watching at my event log and around this time I can see the application "sihost.exe" causing an error.

should I remove sihost.exe? or is there another way to fix this problem?
"sihost.exe" seems to be a original windows service - so I don't know.

**update:** I have also noticed that the startmenu stops working after the taskbar "restarted" itself.

**update 2:** Just noticed that the startmenu works again when I shutdown the restarted explorer.exe and start it again "manually".

thanks for any help!

Comment: @Ramhound yes, correct process name.

Comment: "should I remove sihost.exe?" - Its a system file.

Comment: does version 1607 fix the issue?

Answer (score 3):

No, the SiHost.exe is an important Windows process which provides (with ShellExperienceHost.exe) the new shell (Startmenu, action center, volume changer). Deleting it would break the Windows Shell completely.

[Capture a crash dump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx), zip and share the dmp file. I'll ask my Microsoft contacts for help.

Comment: thank you! as soon as i'll have the time to do it, i try to capture a crash dump. I am on a german windows 10 version if that's important. I've also noticed that the startmenu (by clicking on the windows icon) doesn't work after it all "restarted" itself.

Comment: i got a sihost.exe crah dump-zip here: http://www.filedropper.com/sihostexe8348 (~35 MB) and also a explorer.exe crash dump, explorer seems to immediately crash after sihost: http://www.filedropper.com/explorerexe1288 (~126 MB).

Comment: ok, I go both dumps. I've asked Microsoft for help. seams to be an issue with a notification which crashes the shell.

Comment: ok, thank you! do you know which type of notification causes the problem? and will you get further information?

Comment: no, I only see that the **Windows Push Notification Core** DLL (wpncore.dll) is involved in the Explorer crash

Comment: ok, the Explorer crash happens to more users. MS currently investigates it and tries to fix it. The sihost crash is extremely rare and here MS does nothing. try a different startmenu line StartIsBack++: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557

Comment: ok, thank you very much! will try another startmenu, but still hope for an windows-update that fixes this!

Comment: btw task manager's Processes tab has an interesting feature called "Analyze wait chain" that one can use to see what something frozen is waiting upon