# How do I make windows 10's start menu search work like 7's?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, search, search-indexing

In windows 10, I can't get the start menu's search to show a lot of files that I've recently opened or created (i.e. files on a drive other than the OS drive) when I type the first couple or few letters of the file's name.

I'm comparing it to windows 7's search, which worked beautifully. Example: if I created a new xslx file and save it on drive X:, when I pressed start and typed the first letters of that file's name, it would show up in the search.

In windows 10, it doesn't show up even if I type the entire file's name.

Of course, I don't want to index my entire drives - what *I assume* windows 7 did differently was to index files that I recently opened.

In any case, how do I make the search stop being so crappy? I now have to remember where I placed most of my files. That becomes difficult, and trying to find them when I forget is tedious. Sometimes I have to search my entire drive!

---

I've been searching for a while and I haven't found a solution; forgive me if I've missed it.

Comment: Classic Shell's Classic Start Menu shows more traditional search results. BTW, if you want to index contents of epub, Open Office and LibreOffice documents, DocFetcher can do so, but not Windows Search.

Comment: No sir, I'm not looking to index the contents - just the file name.

Comment: So far, it seems to be significant better. Thanks, DrMoishe.

You should make it an answer to the question.

Comment: simply install a [Win7 Startmenu replacement](https://superuser.com/a/946675/174557) like [StartisBack++](http://startisback.com/#download-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Classic Shell's *Classic Start Menu*](http://www.classicshell.net/) shows more traditional search results.

BTW, if you want to index contents of epub, Open Office and LibreOffice documents, [*DocFetcher*](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) can do so, but not Windows Search. Note that *DocFetcher* requires the Java Runtime Engine (JRE).