# How can I update window/title color in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, aero, windows-10

I mean the this:

[image: How to change the window color here?]

I was able to set a color for the new taskbar and start menu. It is even a little transparent and the background is blurry, like in Windows 7 from which I've updated. Aero Glass is the name, I guess.

I would be fine with just setting a darker color, but aero glass would be perfect!

Comment: I wrote here how to enable Aero Glass again: http://superuser.com/a/946668/174557

Comment: The final of Aero glass DLL is now available. In the TH2 Builds (currently in fast ring for Window Insiders) allow you to change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a detailed guide on [Winaero Blog](http://winaero.com/blog/get-colored-title-bars-in-windows-10/) on how to do this.

There are 2 main options:

- install [Winaero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.1796):

  - run as admin
  - Appearance > Colored Title Bars > Enable Colored Title Bars:

[image]

- do it manually (following is mainly copied from above link - go to that site for screenshots):

  - create a copy of `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero`. SKIP all `MSS` files
  - rename new folder `windows`
  - rename `windows\aero.msstyles` to `windows.aero.msstyles`
  - rename `windows\en-US\aero.msstyles.mui` to `windows.aero.msstyles.mui`
  - copy and paste the `aero.theme` to Desktop
  - rename it to `windows.theme`
  - open with Notepad
  - change the `[VisualStyles]`section's `Path=%ResourceDir%\Themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles` to `Path=%ResourceDir%\Themes\windows\windows.msstyles`
  - save and close
  - double click `windows.theme` and you have colored title bars!

Comment: Works on 8.1 and 10 perfectly. Thanks. A blurry transparent effect would be super awesome but it seems Windows is not ready to add such option for a graphical feature which already existed in Windows 7!!!!! Nevertheless, Thanks :)