# Transparent window backgrounds/titlebars in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, aero, transparency, title-bar

Just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  Found the lack of colored window titlebars to be quite annoying (Chrome, in particular, looked absurd with a white titlebar background), but was able to fix that by follow [the instructions here](http://winaero.com/blog/get-colored-title-bars-in-windows-10/).

The next issue is that the titlebars are no longer transparent as they used to be under Windows 7.  I'd like to turn the transparency back on, and there seem to be various news posts scattered about that imply that Microsoft decided to [reinstate Aero/transparency effects in Windows 10](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/microsoft-tests-aero-glass-comeback-in-windows-10-build-10074/).  However I'm not having any luck finding out where this setting is, or if it even exists.  It seems like it may have only been enabled for the start menu?

Is there a way to make the window titlebars non-opaque in Windows 10, and if so, how?

Comment: Lots of people are asking this question.  The answer is no, you can't make titlebars transparent without third-party, hacky solutions [like this one](http://superuser.com/questions/946667/is-it-possible-to-enable-aero-glass-again-in-windows-10-for-windows-titles?rq=1)

Comment: Happy to settle for a third-party, hacky solution if Microsoft isn't going to play ball.  It's not like it's any great difficulty on their part to allow users to customize the titlebar color and opacity to their liking.  If they won't do that, then bring on the hacks.

Comment: I've already posted a way to reenable it on Windows 10: http://superuser.com/a/946668/174557