# Missing services for Aero Glass on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, aero, aero-peek

As suggested in this thread http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/windows-color-and-appearance-no-aero/ada52f54-8a09-4c5a-95ba-05dc9375fd9a 
I tried to locate `Desktop Window Manager Session Manager` and also start it manual by `net start uxsms`. Same problem With `Themes service`. Seems that none of these services are pre installed on my Windows 10 version. Any chance to install them ?

Answer (score 0):

The DWM is always running since Windows 8 and can't be really stopped without breaking the new Store Apps/Startmenu.

Also since Windows 8, Microsoft removed the Aero Glass effect. [You have to re- enable it with a 3rd party DLL](https://superuser.com/a/946668/174557).

Comment: "can't be really stopped without breaking the new Store Apps/Startmenu" You say that like it's a bad thing...