# Install Win7 on a new Win 10 laptop?

Tags: windows-7

I have a new Toshiba Satellite laptop that came with Win 10.  I'd like to wipe the drive and install Win7.  I can't get the bios to let me format the HDD.  It won't even boot to the ODD.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Finding Win 7 drivers may be an issue

Comment: install StartIsBack to get the Win7 Startmenu (http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557) and Glass8 to get Aero Glass back (http://superuser.com/a/946668/174557) and you have the Win7 UI back if you don't like Win10.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add why you want to do this. Look and feel? Software incompatibility? Don't want some Win10 feature?

Comment: In computing, an optical disc drive (ODD) is a disk drive that uses laser light or electromagnetic waves within or near the visible light spectrum as part of the process of reading or writing data to or from optical discs.   [— Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_drive)

Answer (score 1):

Bring up the Advanced Reboot Menu by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you click the “Reboot” menu entry. A [guide with images is available here](http://www.howtogeek.com/126016/three-ways-to-access-the-windows-8-boot-options-menu/).

From the Reboot Menu, select “Troubleshoot” → “Advanced options” → “UEFI Firmware Settings”. The PC will then reboot and open the settings afterwards. From there, you need to disable Secure Boot to be able to install Windows 7 x64 in UEFI mode. You should also disable Fast Boot to be able to access the UEFI Setup without going through Advanced Reboot.

However, you may find that drivers for certain hardware are no longer available for old operating systems. Please research that first.