# Make Windows 10 Taskbar like Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, taskbar, desktop-customization

Is there any software or steps to make Windows 10 taskbar to look like Windows 7?

It's much clearer if window is open in Windows 7.

[image: Windows 7 Taskbar]

[image: Windows 10 Taskbar]

I don't like absence of non-bottom borders in Windows 10 Taskbar items.

### UPDATE

StartIsBack++ is indeed awesome. And it helped me

- To get start button like Windows 7
- Make taskbar bigger
- Add opacity for my start and taskbar

But my taskbar icons are the same

[image: Start menu]

All the windows are open on screenshot but they still have only bottom border.

even after applying [Windows 7 Themes](http://sagorpirbd.deviantart.com/art/Aero-7-Themes-for-Win10-Final-523979941)

---

Please look at opened but not currently focused window.

Instead of this

[image: win10 explorer taskbar icon]

I want this

[image: win7 explorer taskbar icon]

Comment: You might want to try Classic Shell. I remember it could change my start menu to any windows theme I wanted. I'm not sure about the taskbar itself though.

Comment: I am already using ClassicShell but it is not helpful for my taskbar.

Comment: All you need is Classic Shell. Apply the classic start menu, to look like Windows 98, then change the skin to classic. Change the taskbar color to gray. To make minimized windows look more like Windows 98, right-click on the taskbar and select Properties. In taskbar buttons select Never combine.

Comment: I don't want windows like Windows 98, I want appearance like in Windows 7 (just like first image or similar). I know possibilities you've told.

Comment: [Get Windows XP look in Windows 10 without themes or patches](http://winaero.com/blog/get-windows-xp-look-in-windows-10-without-themes-or-patches/)

Comment: I also don't want Windows XP, I want Windows 7 look.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the transparency of Windows 7 on your taskbar, correct?

Comment: No, I want item borders of active windows in windows 7

Comment: After a thorough search on google, it seems like microsoft has disabled the ability to change the taskbar to your desire in their current build of windows 10. I think you will have to cope with the new taskbar, downgrade to windows 7 or hope that microsoft will make it possible with a new update

Comment: @Michthan StartIsBack++ restores it, but the theme must support it. so he has to ask the theme creator.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov check next week for a Startisback++ update. The author is creating the win7 taskbar in the next version. See the picture in my edit of my answer.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov a beta of the new StartIsBack++ version is now available. try the new version, but remember this is an early beta which is still unstable.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for your updates. Once I face stable StartIsBack++ version with this feature I'll mark you answer as accepted.

Comment: version 2 is now in RC state. test it and send feedback to the developer is you have an issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [StartIsBack++](http://startisback.com/), which brings back [Taskbar Skinning](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/174414-possible-to-change-look-of-windows-10-taskbar/?do=findComment&comment=1113669). Now use [the Windows 7 Theme](http://sagorpirbd.deviantart.com/art/Aero-7-Themes-for-Win10-Final-523979941) for Windows 10 to have the Windows 7 look back.

Starting [with Version 2 of Startisback++, it brings the Windows 7 taskbar](https://twitter.com/StartIsBack/status/822565143347339265) back. See the preview picture:

[image]

[Download StartIsback++ 2](http://startisback.com/#download-tab) to try the new skinning feature.

> - Added support for full taskbar skinning (TrayNotify::Clock, TrayNotify::Toolbar, ShowDesktop::Button, VerticalShowDesktop::Button,
>     Taskband2Composited::TaskBand2, TaskbandExtendedUI)

Open the configuration tool

[image]

and inside `appearance` tab you can select the Windows 7 style to have Windows 7 Taskbar and Windows 7 startmenu look back.

Comment: You have my upvote. Your advice is helpful but it didn't resolve my problem. See update.

Comment: inside StartIsBack++ activate the option to set glass for Taskbar.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see this option. Could you provide more details where is it?

Comment: go to configuration tool of startisback++ and here is an option to color startmenu and taskbar. here you can set it to transparent.

Comment: Thanks, but I was talking about another thing. See update.

Comment: With StartISback++ I see a glow around the icon, but the underlay thing is still there. I like it to see which program is running and which is only pinned to Taskbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49302/discussion-between-vadim-ovchinnikov-and-magicandre1981).

Comment: Could you please update your answer because latest version is not in beta now?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ok, I added the details about final.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try [Winaero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/blog/the-list-of-winaero-tweaker-features/).
It provides the ability to assign Windows 10 the Aero theme from Windows 7 etc. and customize the taskbar opacity.

Edit: Unfortunately after fiddling around with WinAero I cannot find an option to replicate the desired outcome. Apologies.
However, I've noticed that you can assign colours to the taskbar in *Personalize* in Settings. Although this isn't a complete resolution, it makes the taskbar items that are open much more clear. [Taskbar Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RhRp.jpg)

Comment: add more details where you can change this in the tweaker. I see no such option.

Comment: gain, the tool doesn't do what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try WindowBlinds. https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/
It changes the taskbar, the windows and others. However, you may need classic shell to change the start button.