# Make Windows 10 taskbar indicate if 3 or more windows are open

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

***Edit:*** This question differs from [Make Windows 10 Taskbar like Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/1150520/make-windows-10-taskbar-like-windows-7). The linked question asks how to overhaul and reskin the task bar, rather than asking how to make a single specific tweak.

---

In Windows 7, a program's taskbar icon would change to indicate whether you had 1, 2, or 3+ windows open for a single program.

[image: 0 windows] [image: 1 window] [image: 2 windows]  [image: 3 windows]

In Windows 10, no matter how many windows you have open, the taskbar only has indicators for 2 or more open windows.

[image: Windows 10 taskbar with 3 open windows]

I'm aware I can set the taskbar to never combine icons, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

[image: Windows 10 separated icons]

Unhiding taskbar labels also did not solve the issue. Each program was still limited to 2 indicators.

[image: Still only 2 indicators]

**Is there a way to make the Windows 10 taskbar show if a program has 3 or more open windows like it used to in Windows 7?**

Comment: Have you considered setting your taskbar buttons to `Never combine`?  We actually have a GPO on our domains that does that, because the consensus opinion from our end-users is that they prefer to see the rectangle-shaped icons with labels instead of the "deck of cards" look.

Comment: @Run5k I've considered it, but I personally prefer combined icons to avoid taskbar clutter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Windows 10 Taskbar like Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/1150520/make-windows-10-taskbar-like-windows-7)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The linked question asked about changing the border's appearance. My question is about the amount of borders shown per application

Comment: IMO it's the same question -- It asked about making the taskbar look/act like Windows 7's taskbar, which you are also asking.  In the end, the answers are the same, you'll need a 3rd party application to tweak the taskbar, and the ones mentioned in the answers to that question are the same ones that would be mentioned here.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'd seen the linked question before asking mine. Unfortunately, the linked question is fairly broad, asking how to overhaul and fully reskin the Windows task bar. I could not figure out how to make my small tweak from the provided answers.

Comment: It may be true that 3rd party software is required, and even possible that one or both of the products mentioned in the other question is capable of doing this.  But the other thread asks and answers a different question, and I didn't see an obvious answer to this question in either the other thread or the web sites for the products mentioned there.  So The proposed duplicate doesn't address this question.