# How to get a window 10 taskbar on windows 11

Tags: windows, taskbar

I want my windows 10 taskbar back. I don't care so much about the Start Menu, but I want the old taskbar.  Is there anyway to get it?  I am willing to buy something or pay for its open-source development (within the limits of my resources).

One of my favorite laptops got upgraded to Windows 11 (because I was on the insider program to get better WSL support) and I find I no longer use it because I miss the Windows 10 (and prior) task bar where I would make the taskbar have 3 rows and see the titles of all my browser sessions.  I could also put toolbars on the old taskbar to have sets of 2x3, 3x3, or 4x3 icons for things that I used in nice groups.  If I wanted a Apple docker interface, I have a MacBook.  The old taskbar was much nicer.

I want multiple rows.  I want titles for open windows.  Ideally, I also want toolbars.  I don't want to have to go back to Windows 10 to get them.

Comment: Until someone writes one, you can't.

Comment: [Ungroup taskbar items in Windows 11](https://superuser.com/q/1708013/241386)

Answer (score 2):

You could consider Stardock's
[Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/),
which is commercial at €6.99, free for 30-days.

This product is made specially for Windows 11 and has many options.

Answer (score 1):

I found a relevant answer in this question:

[Make Windows 10 Taskbar like Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/1150520/make-windows-10-taskbar-like-windows-7?rq=1)

StartAllBack works on Windows 11 and meets my needs.  I am willing to consider other alternatives, but my problem is solved.  By the way, it does cost money after an initial trial period (100 days as of this posting) if that is a consideration for you.  For me, it is worth it and I don't mind supporting other software developers.